# Is there a column equivalent of `C-l`?

Tags: commands

The command `C-l` scrolls the current line to center, top, bottom. Is there an analogous command that scrolls the current *column* to center, left, and right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be one built-in, however, there is something similar: <kbd>M-g TAB</kbd> - this will ask you for the column to move to.  You can use the function below (bind it to some key you like) to do exactly what you ask:

```lisp
(defun my/goto-midline ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char
   (+ (point)
      (save-excursion
        (/ (- (progn
                (move-end-of-line 1) (point))
              (progn
                (move-beginning-of-line 0) (point)))
           2)))))
```